# transient EntityManager in Java EE

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee

I use **container managed** entityManager within a stateful bean. 
Has this any impact if I use `transient EntityManager`?

```
@Stateful(passivationCapable=false)
public class Session implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -12536865123272541146L;

    // I must use "transient", because EntityManager is not Serializable
    @PersistenceContext
    private transient EntityManager em;

}
```

Comment: Why would it? transient is taken under consideration only while serializing objects

Comment: yes, I know. However, what if @Stateful-bean decides to "serialize" my object? After de-serializing, will the container inject another instance of entityManager from the pool again?

Comment: Btw, as I declared `@Stateful(passivationCapable=false)`, I guess, I dont need to "implement Serializable" at all.

Comment: The container injects another (and not the same) instance of entityManager after de-serializing..